# Incremental commits or only one at the end?

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I'm using python with the mysql.connector to import a large number of lines more than 3 million in a MYSQL database. So I am wondering if I should `cnx.commit()` at the end of the entire data entry or every so often (maybe every 100 entries). Is there a reason to do such a thing or am i overthinking?

Comment: This is a good think to think about up front. ref [insert optimization from manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-optimization.html), especially  note `USE LOAD DATA` if possible. + [innodb bulk data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html). I'd use a bigger batch size - few 1000s but it depends a little on the row size. Feel free to experiment.

Comment: There's a few good answers on [dba exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+insert+speed). Note for [load data connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233244/mysql-connector-in-python-does-not-allow-load-data-infile-syntax). I'm having trouble finding a non-file based interface for python and `load data infile local`. I hope someone else can. But otherwise the large insert options might be ok on 3M lines.